# Extract array elements from another array indices

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array, `a`:

```
a = np.array([[-21.78878256,  97.37484004, -11.54228119],
              [ -5.72592375,  99.04189958,   3.22814204],
              [-19.80795922,  95.99377136, -10.64537733]])
```

I have another array, `b`:

```
b = np.array([[ 54.64642121,  64.5172014,   44.39991983],
              [  9.62420892,  95.14361441,   0.67014312],
              [ 49.55036427,  66.25136632,  40.38778238]])
```

I want to extract minimum value indices from the array, `b`.

```
ixs = [[2],
       [2],
       [2]]
```

Then, want  to extract elements from the array, `a` using the indices, `ixs`:

The expected answer is:

```
result = [[-11.54228119]
          [3.22814204]
          [-10.64537733]]
```

I tried as:

```
ixs = np.argmin(b, axis=1)

print ixs
[2,2,2]

result = np.take(a, ixs)
print result
```

Nope!

Any ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
result = a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), ixs]
```

`np.arange` will generate indices for each row and `ixs` will have indices for each column. So effectively result will have required result.

Comment: more straight, perhaps without `ixs = np.argmin(b, axis=1)` is expected

Comment: You need to do that to find `min` in b

Comment: i do not want to use `result = a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), ixs]`, instead want to do something before it..., any better alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by "before it"... what is the problem doing this?

Comment: i want to replace `ixs = np.argmin(b, axis=1)`

Comment: `a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.argmin(b, axis=1)]` You could just not assign that result to `ixs` if that is what you are looking for. I think some way or the other you will have to find min indices you cant get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below code

```
np.take(a, ixs, axis = 1)[:,0]
```

The initial section will create a 3 by 3 array and slice the first column

```
>>> np.take(a, ixs, axis = 1)

array([[-11.54228119, -11.54228119, -11.54228119],
       [  3.22814204,   3.22814204,   3.22814204],
       [-10.64537733, -10.64537733, -10.64537733]])
```